# Pygments import Lex error

Tags: python, tkinter, pygments

I tried to import lex using this code:

```
from pygments import lex
```

but it only returned an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\samp.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pygments import lex
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\pygments-2.0.2-py3.2.egg\pygments\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from pygments.util import StringIO, BytesIO
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\pygments-2.0.2-py3.2.egg\pygments\util.py", line 226
    return u'[%s-%s]' % (unichr(a), unichr(b))
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**(I'm using Python 3.2.3 on IDLE)**

Is the any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like someone had already logged this as a bug [here](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issues/1054/syntaxerror-on-python-32-using-unicode-u).

Resolution is that -

> Pygments 2.0 requires Python 3.3+.

You should install Python 3.3 or above and then install pygment on that.

Comment: Thank you very much , fixed.